# Separating/combining gulp task sources using yargs and gulp-if

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, yargs

Lets say I want to include all js files in a source folder concatenated in a specific order (using gulp-concat). However, I want to only include certain files if there is a production flag.

For example, in production I need these files:

- modals.js
- utilities.js
- analytics.js
- signup.js
- cookies.js

However, for local and staging, I don't want these two:

- analytics.js
- cookies.js

Is it possible using yargs and perhaps gulp-if to specify this? I know that I could have two lists of sources, for instance:

```
if (argv.production) {
    return gulp.src([
        'modals.js',
        'utilities.js',
        'analytics.js',
        'signup.js',
        'cookies.js'
    ])
} else if (argv.staging) {
    return gulp.src([
        'modals.js',
        'utilities.js',
        'signup.js',
    ])
}
```

However, this would mean I'm not adhering to DRY principles, and just feels silly and prone to error. Can I somehow stitch these together as a single source that only includes things like analytics and cookies if the task has a production flag?

In an ideal world, I could inject gulp if statements inside the gulp.src array that would only include the production-only files if the correct flag were passed.

Some out-loud thinking: 
- Should I just create two files here? One a base that includes everything necessary across environments, and then a production specific one, then combine those? Seems unnecessarily complex, but could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to be a bit more DRY, you can give this a shot, since your set of staging files is a subset of the production files:

```
var base_list = ['modals.js', 'utilities.js', 'signup.js'];
if (argv.staging) {
    return gulp.src(base_list);
} else if (argv.production) {
    var prod_list = base_list.concat(['analytics.js', 'cookies.js']);
    return gulp.src(prod_list);
}
```

Or more simplified (as long as only production needs the other files, and all other environments get the subset):

```
var file_list = ['modals.js', 'utilities.js', 'signup.js'];
if (argv.production) {
    file_list = file_list.concat(['analytics.js', 'cookies.js']);
}
return gulp.src(file_list);
```

There might be some other gulp-specific best practices or tools that could come into play here, but some simple JavaScript might do the trick.